# Laravel 5.4 - copy data from one table to another table, in same database

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, localhost

Is there any way to copy entire data from one table to another table?

Condition:
without making these data to retrieve from one table and storing to array than saving to another table.

Reason according to me:

1. running these entire database on localhost
2. there are nearly avg 100k rows
3. retrieving to array is costly with respect to memory (don't care) but time (important, as entire db on localhost which process slowly)

Comment: You can do this directly in mysql using INSERT AS SELECT or CREATE TABLE AS SELECT.  The only issue with CREATE TABLE AS SELECT is that the structure will match the SELECT so things like constraints, indexes etc, will not necessarily be exactly the same.  Depending on what you want to do this for, that may or may not be important.

Comment: The question is really difficult to understand because of problems with your grammar / sentence structure. You might want to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To copy data from one table and also all the dependent objects of the table, you use the following statements:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_table LIKE existing_table;

INSERT new_table
SELECT * FROM existing_table;
```

From here: [MySQL Copy Table With Examples](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-copy-table-data.aspx)

Comment: $results = \DB::select( "INSERT into archieved_students SELECT * FROM students" );

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = DB::select( DB::raw("CREATE TABLE tbl_new AS SELECT * FROM tbl_old;'") );
```

I believe you will get what you want.

comment on this answer if you need more info

Comment: this worked $results = \DB::select( "INSERT into archieved_students SELECT * FROM students" );